# Are Isaac Asimov's views borne out through Dr Calvin?

Tags: isaac-asimov, i-robot

Susan Calvin is the effective narrator of the *I, Robot* short story compilation. Towards the end we see her view that humanity is best ruled by robots, as we have no idea what is best for ourselves, she is distrustful of humans and has 'faith' in Robots due to the Three Laws.

Is she, in essence, a voice for Isaac Asimov's views on humanity? OR have I interpreted her/the author wrongly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insofar as Susan Calvin was a supremely rational, unsentimental character, she represented Asimov's way of thinking, at least as can be inferred from his public comments.

In particular I recommend Asimov's essays and talks on overpopulation to get a feel for his attitude and approach to apprehending and attacking problems.  The 1970's era essays are likely out-of-print but some of the talks and some interviews can be found on YouTube.

Assuming we actually do develop [friendly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_artificial_intelligence) strong AI, it seems a reasonable extrapolation that Asimov would be in favor of turning ever increasing amounts of long term planning over to such intelligences.  There's little point in doing the difficult work of developing a higher order of intelligence and then ignoring its advice.